# basic reading input from user in java

Tags: java, input, system.in

I want to read a character and store it into the `char[]` array and here is my method called `getaline`

```
public static int getaline(char message[], int maxlength)
{
     int index = 0;
     while (message[index] != '\n')
     {
         message[index] = fgetc(System.out);
         index++;
     }
     index++;
}
```

and my `fgetc` method:

```
public static int fgetc(InputStream stream)
```

and this method should returns a character from the input stream.

But i keep getting an error message when i compile:

> error: possible loss of precision

```
message[index] = fgetc(System.in);
                       ^
required: char

found:    int
```

what should i put inside `fgetc` so that i can collect input from the user??

Answer (score 5):

Your code is expecting a `char`, but you return an `int` here:

```
public static int fgetc(InputStream stream)
//            ↑ tells method will return an int
```

You can

- Change method signature to return a `char`.

  ```
  public static char fgetc(InputStream stream)
  //            ↑ tells method will return a char
  ```
- Cast returned value to `char`

  > **Casting conversion** ([§5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)) converts the type of an expression to a type explicitly specified by a cast operator ([§15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)).

  ```
  message[index] = (char) fgetc(System.in);
  //               ↑ cast returning value to a char
  ```